# Oz VeHadar Chumash HaRamban

Tags: ramban

Does anyone have experience using the Oz Vehadar Chumash HaRamban? If so, would you recommend this set? Does it really enhance one's understanding of Ramban and Rashi?

https://ozvehadar.us/chumash-ramban-hamevuar-10-volumes/

Comment: I didn't downvote but it is always easier to answer these questions if you ask fact-based questions rather than ask for personal opinions from people you don't know.

Comment: "_Does it really enhance one's understanding of Ramban and Rashi?_" Who claims it enhances one's understanding of Ramban and Rashi?

Comment: Why would they write a commentary that does not attempt to enhance one's understanding?

Comment: @Bs234570 (When responding to someone's comment, it is best to put `@<UserName>` in your comment, like I did at the beginning of this comment for you. That way he gets informed of your comment.) "_Why would they write a commentary that does not attempt to enhance one's understanding?_" Possibly they print the commentary only to make it readily available to people, and leave enhancement of knowledge as an exercise for the readers.